# Proof $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$ when $A$ Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I was trying to understand a proof of why a Hermitian $A$ matrix has its eigenvectors orthogonal. As part of the proof they state
$$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$$

From which property this is derived

Comment: Isn't that the definition of $A^*$?

Comment: Well, that equality is true *always* : it is , in fact, how the adjoint matrix (transformation) is defined!

Comment: By far, the definition of *hermitian matrix* $A$ I see the most is $A=A^*$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For any vectors $u,v$, we have $\langle u,v \rangle = v^*u$.  Thus,
$$
\langle Ax,y \rangle = y^*(Ax)
$$
We'd like to show that the above is equal to
$$
\langle x,A^*y \rangle = (A^*y)^*x
$$
How do we get from one to the other?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @GitGud Somebody obviously felt it was worth the $1$ point to express their disapproval, but not worth the $1$ second to explain express their issue with my answer.

Comment: I was forgetting to calculate the Hermitian of one of the factors before multiplying the factors.
@Omnomonomnom Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : I don't understand the downvote either.  Personally I prefer Hermitian inner products that are linear in the second argument, but from the OP's question, it is not apparent which convention the OP is using.  This is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{A = A\+\quad\imp\quad\mbox{real eigenvalues}\ \braces{\lambda_{i}}}$. With a pair of eigenvectors $v_{i}$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}$ of $A$ $\pars{~Av_{i} = \lambda_{i}v_{i}\,,\quad i = 1,2~}$:
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
v_{1}\+v_{2}}
= {1 \over \lambda_{2}}\,v_{1}\+\lambda_{2}v_{2}
= {1 \over \lambda_{2}}\,v_{1}\+A v_{2}
= {1 \over \lambda_{2}}\,\pars{v_{2}\+ A v_{1}}\+
= {1 \over \lambda_{2}}\,\pars{v_{2}\+\lambda_{1}v_{1}}\+
= \color{#0000ff}{\large{\lambda_{1} \over \lambda_{2}}\,v_{1}\+ v_{2}}
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lambda_{1} \not= \lambda_{2}\quad\imp\quad v_{1}\+v_{2} = 0}$$

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question?

The adjoint matrix $A^*$ of $A$ is by definition a matrix that satisfies
\begin{align}
\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,A^*y \rangle,
\end{align}
for all $x$ and $y$. Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is called the inner product, and in a complex vector space it is defined as
\begin{align}
\langle x,y\rangle = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}x_i \overline{y}_i,
\end{align}
where $\overline{y}$ is the complex conjugate of $y$ and $n$ is the length of the vectors $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Why are you mentioning the real inner product?

Comment: @GitGud You're right, I just thought he didn't know what the adjoint was, and I didn't even notice that he mentioned the Hermitian matrix. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This result is based on [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem). The theorem states that any linear functional $ f(a) \in  \mathbb F , \forall a \in \mathbb F^n,$ can be represented as $f(a)=(a|b)$ where $b \in \mathbb F^n$.

For a given $y, (Ax|y)=f(x)$ therefore $\exists b:(Ax|y)=(x|b),$ let $A^*y=b$ we get $(Ax|y)=(x,A^*y)$, $A^*$ can be proved to be unique.

Also this is true for all $A$. If $A$ is Hermitian, then $(Ax|y)=(x|Ay)$ because $A=A^*$